# Skrollr full section parallax effect

Tags: parallax, skrollr

I am struggling to achieve a full section parallax effect. I am looking to basically emulate http://rachelplatten.com/#intro.

This website works specifically on mobile (ios) as well pretty smoothly. I am trying to use Skrollr to achieve the effect. On this website on scroll, it unveils the next div.

In my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVRzJg) the blue overlaps the photo instead of unveiling. I've tried using data-anchor-targets with no luck as well. Perhaps my css is wrong. I'm planning to have an unknown number of sections, so if I can setup a basic structure to where that would work it would be great. I'm new to skrollr and am hoping for any advice.

```
<section data-center="transform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);" data-top-bottom="transform:translate3d(0px, 500px, 0px);">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but you may find it helpful to look at Prinzhorn's [classic parallax example](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/classic.html) as that is more or less what the site you linked does.

From what I understand (if you're planning on the site being mobile-friendly) you pre-load all of the images you will use as backgrounds, then use them to fill in `.gap` divs.